# Is it possible to hide Keycloak's interface from users?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I would like to hide Keycloak's interface from my Customers.

Is it possible to login to Keycloak through an API (specially for Authorization Code grant type), so I can build a React component for example for my customers to login?

Is it possible to build my own Account app, that will interact with Keycloak through an API?

Only my staff should use Keycloak's interface to manage security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect your application to the Keycloak login page, and change that login page to have the looks and feel that you desire using Keycloak [Custom Themes](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/custom-themes-for-keycloak-631bdd3e04e5). To communicate from your Account app to Keycloak Api you can use the [Keycloak Admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html).

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to customize the login page up to the limits allowed by Keycloak, I hope the options are good, and use that Admin API to build my own account manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, almost every SPA (Angular, React, Vue, ...) developer dreams about replacing of IdP (Keycloak in your case) login screen (because default IdP login is ugly/it doesn't match app style/... and he can build cool login screen on the SPA level :-)).

Sure, it's possible. Switch to `Direct Access Grants` (`Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant`) and you can use that. But you will sacrifice security. Let's say you have Google IDP identity brokering, so users will be able to use also own Google account. Will you put your Google credentials to some custom login form, which claims that those credentials will be used only to login and they won't be stolen. I would say no, because app will see your credentials. That is purpose of IdP (OIDC or SAML protocol). It provides user identity to any app (especially for 3rd party apps) without exposing user credentials - that is perfect case for `Authorization Code` grant type.

So I would say it's possible to use own SPA login form, but it is wrong idea. I would use local app auth in you case.

Second question: you can build own Account based on Account REST API. It is pretty new, so there is no good doc for that and it's only available as an preview feature. New account console should use it - https://www.keycloak.org/2020/09/new-account-console.adoc.html, so you can watch network browser console to see API requests.